# Hanging bed from cement ceiling

Tags: ceiling, hanging, hardware, cement

I saw a thread on here that kind of discussed this, but I am trying to hang a queen platform bed from a cement ceiling in a Loft apartment model.  It will not be used, just more decoration, although someone may sit on it.  The building is old probably 1920's cement ceiling. Can I use Red Head Multi-set II Drop in Anchors?  4 ropes to hold the four corners of the bed.

Comment: I would not do it. I am always leery of hanging stuff from old concrete ceilings.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you are hanging a fake bed in a model apartment? Have you consulted legal counsel on what would happen if anything went wrong with this plan?